# Find if sphere is inside parallelepiped

Tags: cubics, spheres

I have many spheres in a 3D space, with their center's position and their radius to be known. I also have 1 parallelepiped ( [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped)) with its 8 vertices' positions to be also known.

How can I check if any of the spheres is "touching" or is inside (partly or whole) the parallelepiped or is completely out of the parallelepiped ?

If anybody can help I would be thankful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is actually asking the distance of a point (center) to several (6) planes, which is intuitively defined by the length of line segment from the point to the plane which is perpendicular to the plane. After rephrasing the question will be very easy if you know vector.

Since you know the coordinate of vertices, to find the distance of center of sphere to faces of parallelepiped, pick vertices that are in the same face and find 2 vectors on this face (which will be edges or diagonals of a face). Compute the cross product and you will get the normal vector to this face. Find the line through the center of the sphere parallel to the normal and find the point intersected by this line and the face. Find the distance of this intersection and the center of sphere and compare to radius. You have to check for all 6 faces then done.

Comment: and if a sphere is far away form the paralellepiped but still the perpendicular line I will find is smaller than the radius (this can happen I think) ? Then I will have wrong result for my sphere.

Comment: Or if the sphere is partly inside the paralellepiped and is in one of the vertices of the paralellepiped, how am I going to ind the perpendicular lines?

Comment: @Thanos Kw You are right I missed this case. If we don't care about the most convenient method, add one more step to check whether the center of sphere is inside the parallelepiped is plausible. To make the check easier, you can do translation and rotation so that one vertex is the origin and 2 edges are $x,y$ axes. Also, after the translation and rotation, computing the distance from face to center of sphere will be much easier.

Comment: Another idea is that you can pick directions the normals so that all of them point outward. However with only coordinates of vertices are given, I don't think it is an easy way.

Comment: I didn't understand either of the 2 methods you are suggesting :( if you could be more analytic I would appreciate it. Generally, I think that a good mathematical and fast way is to find the equation(s) that express every point of space inside the paralellepiped (that exists, but I haven't been able to find it in the internet) and then consider also offset of the value of the radius of the sphere, and check if the center of the sphere+/-radius confirms the equations. If it does,that means that the sphere overlaps with the paralellepiped.

Comment: i forgot to tag your name.

Comment: @Thanos Kw For example, if $A$ are three points, and I want $A=(x_a, y_a, z_a)$ to be origin. Then I just subtract $(x_a, y_a, z_a)$ from all points, and call them primes. Translation is done. If $AB$ is one edge and you want to make it $x'$-axis, $AC$ and $AB$ are on the same face, let $AC \times AB$ be $z'$-axis, Then you got information of $x'y'$ plane, $x'z'$ plane, $y'z'$ plane, and new coordinates of vertices can be found. This is indeed messy, but not that too messy, because parallelepiped have a bunch of parallel edges.

Comment: Draw a picture will be very helpful. Also when you want to determine which direction of normal is "outward", picture will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I did it with an other way. The math was trickier than I thought.